# How do we retrieve values of Custom Lists(dropdown) in Netsuite

Tags: web-services, netsuite, suitetalk

I have record type "XYZ" which has field called "award area" which is of type list/record. "award area" is of type custom list and is a drop down control.

Using Suitetalk how can I retrieve those values from that drop down?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40498201/2912011) should work. It's for translating the results from the internalId's returned into the actual text type, you maybe be able to leverage it in another way. Maybe you could create a lookup list with something like this(C#):

```
public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<long, string>> getCustomFieldLists()
{
    return
        nsService.search(new CustomListSearch())
            .recordList.Select(a => (CustomList) a)
            .ToDictionary(a => a.name,
                a => a.customValueList.customValue
                     .ToDictionary(b => b.valueId, c => c.value));
}

var valueLookup = getCustomFieldLists()["award area"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it for myself, because I was irritated with the fact the NetSuite doesn't just provide us an easy way to access these. And I wanted the following data for reference:

- The Internal ID of the Custom List
- The Name of the Custom List
- The Internal ID of the Custom List Item
- The name Value of the Custom List Item

[image: Screenshot of what I wanted to get]

I wanted/needed access to all of those things, and I wanted to be able to obtain the name Value of the Custom List Item by just providing the Internal ID of the Custom List and the Internal ID of the Custom List Item. So, in my homemade integration client, similar to David Rogers' answer, but without all the fancy Linq, I figured out that the best solution was a Dictionary>>.

This way, for the outer Dictionary, I could set the key to the internal IDs of the Custom Lists, and for the inner Dictionary I could set the key to the internal IDs of the Custom List Items themselves. Then, I would get the name of the Custom List for "free" as the beginning part of the Tuple, and the actual name Value for "free" as the value of the internal Dictionary.

Below is my method code to generate this object:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the collection of all custom lists, and places it in the public CustomListEntries object
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
private Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, Dictionary<long, string>>> GetCustomLists()
{
    Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, Dictionary<long, string>>> customListEntries = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, Dictionary<long, string>>>();
    SearchPreferences sp = SuiteTalkService.searchPreferences; //Store search preferences to reset back later, just need body fields this one time
    SuiteTalkService.searchPreferences = new SearchPreferences() { bodyFieldsOnly = false };
    SearchResult sr = SuiteTalkService.search(new CustomListSearch());
    SuiteTalkService.searchPreferences = sp; //Restore search preferences

    foreach (CustomList cl in sr.recordList)
    {
        Dictionary<long, string> customListItems = new Dictionary<long, string>();
        if (cl.customValueList == null) continue;
        foreach (CustomListCustomValue clcv in cl.customValueList.customValue)
        {
            customListItems.Add(clcv.valueId, clcv.value);
        }
        customListEntries.Add(cl.internalId, new Tuple<string, Dictionary<long, string>>(cl.name, customListItems));
    }
    return customListEntries;
}
```

Then, in the constructors of my Integration class, I can set my object to the return result:

```
public Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, Dictionary<long, string>>> CustomListEntries = GetCustomLists();
```

And finally, whenever I need access TO those values, since I set all of this up ahead of time, I can do the following:

```
dr[Class] = SuiteTalkIntegrator.CustomListEntries[lorr.typeId].Item2[long.Parse(lorr.internalId)];
```

In this case above, my "lorr" object is a ListOrRecordRef object that I obtained from the SearchColumnSelectCustomField.searchValue from the search results of a SavedSearch. I don't know if this will work for anyone else that finds this code, but since I was frustrated in finding an easy answer to this problem, I thought I'd share my solution with everyone.

Frankly, I'm most frustrated that this functionality isn't just given to us out of the box, but I've noticed that NetSuite has made a lot of bad design choices in their SuiteTalk API, like not making a custom class of "RecordField" for their record fields and not placing their record fields under an IEnumerable of RecordField so that programmers can loop through all values in a record in a generic way without having to EXPLICITLY name them and re-construct the same code logic over and over again... ugh...